# PHP5: What PHP function outputs Users IP address, Platform and Browser?

Tags: php, ip, orientation, user-experience

Of all these functions that return current visitors info/ip *only the **first** one* seems to output:

```
echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

echo $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"];
echo $_SERVER["HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP"];
echo $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"];
echo $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"];
```

Primary Question: **Why the other functions dont output anything?**

Bonus Question: **Are there any other cool functions** in this regard for example a function that outputs the visitors used browser & platform??   Also usefull would be to get the visitors city, favourite beverage, favourite color in #RGB...  :) Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You want to use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` for the IP, and regex out the platform and browser from `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` but don't rely on it too much - user agent strings can be spoofed very easily.

Numerous firefox extensions can have you becoming anything from Googlebot to Safari on iPhone and everything in between. firefox's `about:config` also has a param to edit it (that's how the extension works), etc etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It's not functions but array members.
2. It's **not IP address** they output but *HTTP headers* (Note `HTTP_` in them)
3. The only one contains IP address is `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`

> Why the other functions dont output anything?

Because these HTTP headers are optional.

> Are there any other cool functions

Sure

```
print_r($_SERVER);
```

will show you them all

Note [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-browser.php) function which helps you to get more structured info out of User-Agent header.

Answer (score 1):

Using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] will get you something like:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS
>   X; en) AppleWebKit/418 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Safari/417.9.3

Which you can use to work out the operating system and browser.

Answer (score 1):

just try, and get what you want:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($GLOBALS);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: this would be quite excessive

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use something like this :

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

to see what's in the `$_SERVER` variable : there, you'll find plenty of useful stuff, amongst the HTTP Headers sent by the browser.

Like, for instance :

- `HTTP_USER_AGENT` : indicates the User-Agent string sent by the browser

  - For example, mine is `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; fr; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110323 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.16`
- and `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`: indicates the languages preferences sent by the browser

  - For example, mine are : `fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3`

Note : those are indications -- only !

- They can be faked *(and even contain malicious data)*
- They can not be there.

Then, when it comes to finding the IP address of a user :

- `REMOTE_ADDR` is the item that generally contains this information
- But it can be in another item, generally when the user is behing a proxy -- hence the *forwarded* headers.

Answer (score 1):

**Primary Answer:**
at the server you can output only the information the browser gave you. So if the browser did not send the information "HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP", the server and of course php are not able to output it.

Besides this, the [documentation](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) of $_SERVER does not contain anything like "HTTP_FORWARDED".

**Bonus Answer:**
Due to the fact that the browser does not send those information per default, you have to get them via JS and send them by your on, just like tracking tools do (have a look at piwik, it is open code) or grap them from other information you get, like $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] (see comment)